# innerHTML does not work when showing Tweet content

Tags: javascript, html

In Html file, I test showing tweet content with

```
<div class="container" id="trackingResults">
         <p id="printout">
            <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-link-color="#55acee" lang="es">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/jack/status/20">    
            </a>
            </blockquote></p>
</div>
```

it works well
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV4Un.png)

then when i try to generate the content with js function

```
var trackingResults = document.getElementById('printout');
trackingResults.innerHTML = '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-link-color="#55acee" lang="es"><a href="https://twitter.com/jack/status/20"></a></blockquote>';
```

It does not work,
[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Qfk.png)

Basically, I just copied same content to innerHTML property, but it shows the different results.

I do not know why.

Comment: You should use `outerHTML`

Comment: Can you create a working demo of your problem?

Comment: `outerHTML` no! "If the element has no parent element, that is if it is the root element of the document, setting its outerHTML property will throw a DOMException with the error code NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR.": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: have written something function for `.twitter-tweet` in js. if so you have to re call that function after you set innerHTML, which will re-request and replace

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets#js-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are using Twitter api which convert your `blockquote` to properly formatted twitter tweet iframe, which works on page load event. And on changing innerHTML it does not work because that library do not bind on the newly added code. Due to which you are seeing nothing.

Comment: This seems the reason I can not get proper results. So how could I generate many tweets dynamically with this kind format?

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating an element using

[Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

```
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement () { 
  // create a new div element 
  // and give it some content 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
   
$('#trackingResults').html('<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-link-color="#55acee" lang="es"><a href="https://twitter.com/jack/status/20"></a></blockquote>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="trackingResults">
        
</div>
```